Lines on cubic threefold in characteristic 3
Altman and Kleiman in Foundations of the theory of Fano schemes prove that if $F = F_1(X) \subset \mathbb G(1, 4) = G$ is a Fano scheme of lines on cubic threefold in $\mathbb P^4$ with at most finitely many double points, then the natural map induced by restriction
$$
H^0(G, \mathcal O(2)) \rightarrow H^0(F, \mathcal O(2))
$$
is injective whenever $\mathbb k$ is algebraically closed field of characteristic not $3$, and thus every quadric hypersurface containing $F$ in the Plucker embedding must also contain $G$ at least in characteristic not $3$.
Sadly authors do not mention what happens in the excluded case of characteristic $3$. I'm curious if such quadric can be constructed explicitely in any elegant/compact form (provided it even exists, what also to me is not immediately clear, as the proof is not constructive)
